# htaccess to pretty url

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to apply "pretty" URLs to my website.

ie: `localhost/chess/game.php?id=10`

to

```
localhost/chess/game/10
```

heres my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteBase /chess/
RewriteRule ^games$ games.php
RewriteRule ^new$ newgame.php
RewriteRule ^game/(\d+)*$ game.php?id=$1
```

It's working good for games and new, but for game it shows me the page without styling and showing my error 'no game'

How can I fix this htaccess?
Do I need to change the php file where I read the get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be in your `/chess/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /chess/

RewriteRule ^games/?$ games.php [L]
RewriteRule ^new/?$ newgame.php [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^game/(\d+)/?$ game.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

- Also make sure to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
- You can also try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />`

Answer (score 1):

The styling error is probably due to the path you are using for your styles.

If you are using relative paths: `styles/css.css` then this would work fine on the home page, however if you are accessing this file from `/game/` then the browser would be looking for the file in `game/styles/css.css`

Assuming your styles are accessible via the root of the site you can add a `/` to the beginning of the css route so the browser would pull them from the root path.

Example: `/styles/css.css`

Comment: Yes, can be this problem too. But is showing me the error that I dont have permission to see this game, so its not reading the session